# How to customise tooltips with bokeh/holoviews/datashader

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I am visualising a large dataframe with holoviews/bokeh and want to customise the tooltips.
I'll exemplify:

```
import bokeh
import datashader as ds
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, shade, dynspread, spread, rasterize
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

Creating mock data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
N = int(10e6)
x_r = (0,100)
y_r = (100,2000)
z_r = (0,10e8)
x = np.random.randint(x_r[0]*1000,x_r[1]*1000,size=(N, 1))
y = np.random.randint(y_r[0]*1000,y_r[1]*1000,size=(N, 1))
z = np.random.randint(z_r[0]*1000,z_r[1]*1000,size=(N, 1))
z2 = np.ones((N,1)).astype(int)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x,y,z,z2]), columns=['x','y','z','z2'])
df[['x','y','z']] = df[['x','y','z']].div(1000, axis=0)
df
```

And then visualise away:

```
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
palette = get_cmap('viridis')
# palette_inv = palette.reversed()

p=hv.Points(df,['x','y'], ['z','z2'])

P=rasterize(p, aggregator=ds.sum("z2"),x_range=(0,100)).opts(cmap=palette)
P.opts(tools=["hover"]).opts(height=500, width=500,xlim=(0,100),ylim=(100,2000))
```

This however shows the tooltip for `z2` as `x_y z2`, and x/y need custom annotations, too so I:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ('custom1','$y{0.000}'),('custom2','$x{0.000}'),('custom3','@{x_y z2}{0.0}')
])
hover.point_policy='snap_to_data'
hover.line_policy='none'

P.opts(default_tools = [], tools=[hover,"wheel_zoom","box_zoom","reset"])
```

**But** `custom3` is displayed as the literal `'${x_y z2}{0.0}'`. Using `'@{x_y z2}{0.0}'` - shows `'???'`; as does `'@z2'`.
Just in case the above `'x_y z2'` indicates stacking, tried using `'@$z2{0.0}'` - shows no tooltip at all; as does `'$z2'`.

I followed the [bokeh doc](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool) which the respective [holoviews docs section](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html#hover-tools) references, and now I'm out of things to try. There must be some way to access the value dimensions, since it's shown in the default hover. Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and managed to get it to work by linking 'x_y' and the data item using an '_', so in your example it would be
`@{x_y_z2}{0.0}`

Give that a try and see if it works, it works in my situation.